# ROS2 Humble camera_ros camera_node gives sporadic segmentation faults. How can I fix this?

Tags: ros-humble, camera, raspberry-pi

I am trying to create a simple, repeatable recipe for setting up IMX219 picam2 using ROS2 Humble on a Rasberry Pi 4.  I am trying to install as much from binaries as possible, starting from the Ubuntu Server 22.04.4 (64 bit) image for rpi loaded by rpi-imager.

The camera sometimes works, and can send video to a pc running rqt on Lubuntu 22.04 with ROS2 Humble.  However only the compressed topic works (and it sometimes seg faults).  The raw topic *always* causes a seg fault when viewed in rqt.

```
locale

LANG=en_GB.UTF.8
LANGUAGE=
LC_CTYPE="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=en_GB.UTF-8
```

ROS2 installation:

```
sudo apt install software-properties-common
sudo add-apt-repository universe
sudo apt update && sudo apt install curl -y
sudo curl -sSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ros/rosdistro/master/ros.key -o /usr/share/keyrings/ros-archive-keyring.gpg
echo "deb [arch=$(dpkg --print-architecture) signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/ros-archive-keyring.gpg] http://packages.ros.org/ros2/ubuntu $(. /etc/os-release && echo $UBUNTU_CODENAME) main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros2.list > /dev/null
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
sudo apt install ros-humble-ros-base
sudo apt install ros-dev-tools
```

Camera packages:

```
sudo apt-install ros-humble-camera-ros
sudo apt install libcamera0
sudo apt install libcamera-tools
sudo apt install v4l-utils
```

/boot/firmware/config.txt

```
[all]
kernel=vmlinuz
cmdline=cmdline.txt
initramfs initrd.img followkernel

[pi4]
max_framebuffers=2
arm_boost=1

[all]
# Enable the audio output, I2C and SPI interfaces on the GPIO header. As these
# parameters related to the base device-tree they must appear *before* any
# other dtoverlay= specification
dtparam=audio=on
dtparam=i2c_arm=on
dtparam=spi=on

# Comment out the following line if the edges of the desktop appear outside
# the edges of your display
disable_overscan=1

# If you have issues with audio, you may try uncommenting the following line
# which forces the HDMI output into HDMI mode instead of DVI (which doesn't
# support audio output)
#hdmi_drive=2

# Enable the serial pins
enable_uart=1

# Autoload overlays for any recognized cameras or displays that are attached
# to the CSI/DSI ports. Please note this is for libcamera support, *not* for
# the legacy camera stack
camera_auto_detect=1
display_auto_detect=1

# Config settings specific to arm64
arm_64bit=1
dtoverlay=dwc2
dtoverlay=imx219

[cm4]
# Enable the USB2 outputs on the IO board (assuming your CM4 is plugged into
# such a board)
dtoverlay=dwc2,dr_mode=host

[all]
```

Firmware version:

```
vcgencmd version
Oct 26 2022 11:09:05 
Copyright (c) 2012 Broadcom
version c72ad6b26ff40c91ef776b847436094ee63fabee (clean) (release) (start)
```

camera_ros output:

```
ros2 run camera_ros camera_node --ros-args -p width:=800 -p height:=600
[0:28:24.511215089] [1463]  INFO Camera camera_manager.cpp:284 libcamera v0.2.0
[0:28:24.553139433] [1473]  WARN RPiSdn sdn.cpp:39 Using legacy SDN tuning - please consider moving SDN inside rpi.denoise
[0:28:24.555477392] [1473]  WARN RPI vc4.cpp:347 Mismatch between Unicam and CamHelper for embedded data usage!
[0:28:24.557771815] [1473]  INFO RPI vc4.cpp:401 Registered camera /base/soc/i2c0mux/i2c@1/imx219@10 to Unicam device /dev/media0 and ISP device /dev/media1
[INFO] [1711872566.638805828] [camera]: 
>> cameras:
   0: imx219 (/base/soc/i2c0mux/i2c@1/imx219@10)
[WARN] [1711872566.639101421] [camera]: no camera selected, using default: "/base/soc/i2c0mux/i2c@1/imx219@10"
[INFO] [1711872566.639756086] [camera]: 
>> stream formats:
   - Pixelformat: NV21 (64x64 - 3280x2464)
   - Pixelformat: YUV420 (64x64 - 3280x2464)
   - Pixelformat: NV12 (64x64 - 3280x2464)
   - Pixelformat: YVU420 (64x64 - 3280x2464)
   - Pixelformat: XBGR8888 (64x64 - 3280x2464)
   - Pixelformat: BGR888 (64x64 - 3280x2464)
   - Pixelformat: RGB888 (64x64 - 3280x2464)
   - Pixelformat: XRGB8888 (64x64 - 3280x2464)
   - Pixelformat: RGB565 (64x64 - 3280x2464)
   - Pixelformat: YVYU (64x64 - 3280x2464)
   - Pixelformat: YUYV (64x64 - 3280x2464)
   - Pixelformat: VYUY (64x64 - 3280x2464)
   - Pixelformat: UYVY (64x64 - 3280x2464)
[WARN] [1711872566.639910716] [camera]: no pixel format selected, using default: "XBGR8888"
[WARN] [1711872566.640076993] [camera]: stream configuration adjusted from "800x600-XBGR8888" to "800x600-XBGR8888"
[0:28:24.559400738] [1463]  INFO Camera camera.cpp:1183 configuring streams: (0) 800x600-XBGR8888
[0:28:24.560070756] [1473]  INFO RPI vc4.cpp:559 Sensor: /base/soc/i2c0mux/i2c@1/imx219@10 - Selected sensor format: 1640x1232-SBGGR10_1X10 - Selected unicam format: 1640x1232-pBAA
[INFO] [1711872566.642433915] [camera]: camera "/base/soc/i2c0mux/i2c@1/imx219@10" configured with 800x600-XBGR8888 stream
[WARN] [1711872566.643301081] [camera]: control HdrMode (41) not handled
[WARN] [1711872566.643996246] [camera]: control StatsOutputEnable (20001) not handled
[WARN] [1711872566.644086783] [camera]: control NoiseReductionMode (10002) not handled
[WARN] [1711872566.644522357] [camera]: control AeFlickerPeriod (10) not handled
[WARN] [1711872566.645119689] [camera]: control AeFlickerMode (9) not handled
[INFO] [1711872567.003914049] [camera]: using default calibration URL
[INFO] [1711872567.004107790] [camera]: camera calibration URL: file:///home/paul/.ros/camera_info/imx219__base_soc_i2c0mux_i2c_1_imx219_10_800x600.yaml
[ERROR] [1711872567.004371067] [camera_calibration_parsers]: Unable to open camera calibration file [/home/paul/.ros/camera_info/imx219__base_soc_i2c0mux_i2c_1_imx219_10_800x600.yaml]                                                             
[WARN] [1711872567.004472419] [camera]: Camera calibration file /home/paul/.ros/camera_info/imx219__base_soc_i2c0mux_i2c_1_imx219_10_800x600.yaml not found
```

Comment: Now I have tried building libcamera from source using Raspberry Pi's version of libcamera https://github.com/raspberrypi/libcamera.git,  Unfortunately it is every bit as unreliable as the version from Ubuntu repository.  The crashes seem related to memory usage - raw topic works for 320x230 pixels.  Only compressed works for larger frame sizes.